# Program that returns "1" if LAN is connected and "0" if not

Tags: c, windows, connection, lan, listen

I want to listen to my LAN port. If the PC is connected to the internet over LAN, the program should return LAN="1". If the PC is off-line or not connected over LAN, the program should return LAN="0". Is there a simple way to solve the problem?

Comment: What have you tried so far? And if you haven't done so yet, please read [the Stack Overflow question checklist](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/156810/stack-overflow-question-checklist). You might also want to learn what a [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/) is.

Comment: `solve the problem simple` if simple then why not show you.

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa384702.aspx

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.networkinformation.networkinterface.getisnetworkavailable(v=vs.110).aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=cpp#code-snippet-1